# What is right method to repopulate field values after submit.?

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I am using sessions to repopulate values in form,Its look something like this
    My form have some fields and I want to populate  user entered values after sever side validattions.Below is the form:

```
<html>
<form>
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['NAME'])) echo $_SESSION['NAME'];?>" >

Address:<input type="text" id="address" name="address"  value=<?php if(isset($_SESSION['ADDRESS'])) echo $_SESSION['ADDRESS']; ?>> 

</form>
</html>
```

I am storing the values in action page like this:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['NAME']    = $strname ;
$_SESSION['ADDRESS'] = $straddress;
?>
```

want to know whether this is the right way to do it,to populate user entered values after server side validation.Although it works fine.

Comment: I believe `$_SESSION` is useful if this information is shared across multiple pages. However, if this will be used to populate _only_ on  the same page, you can save them in variables like `$name`, `$address` after server side validations and escape functions, then display those variable values on the respective fields.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store it in session variables if you need it to use just after you have posted the form. You can either use $_POST or $_GET depending upon the form submission method you use.

Also you can use [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function on $_POST or $_GET to get the posted values using it's field name.